# using javascript quotes in php code

Tags: php, javascript, confirmation

i'm having some trouble using javasript in php code, I'm confused  in using double quotes and single quotes.

```
echo '<a href="shop.php?buy=1" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")">Delete</a>';
```

or how to do the above code in php ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

```
echo '<a href="shop.php?buy=1" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete?\')">Delete</a>';
```

you have to escape the quotes.

http://viper-7.com/F6uI0L

Comment: uh, i remember using / , but not sure or forgot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the quotes with `htmlspecialchars` (for HTML):

```
echo '<a href="..." onclick="return confirm('
   .htmlspecialchars('"Are you sure"') . '">Delete</a>';
```

(alternatively you could just write `&quot`;)

...but don't do that.  Use JS event registration:

```
document.getElementById('a-id').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure...")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Do that in JS file.  It requires that the `<a>` have an ID (you could also do it with a host of other selectors, but ID is the simplest).

Comment: You'll need to escape single quotes. `\"` will be a JS syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Change like following

```
echo "<a href=\"shop.php?buy=1\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the HTML outside of PHP tags? For example you could do:

```
...
?>

<a href="shop.php?buy=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>

<?php
...
```

Another way to echo HTML is:

```
echo <<<HTML
<a href="shop.php?buy=1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>
HTML
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the quotes in heredoc syntax, in fact, it won't work if you do.

Comment: I didn't want to, I just pasted the copied HTML and and hit update answer by accident. Actually I'm on on iPad now and it's very hard to edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Error in `confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")">` you need to escape double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the javascript function using php echo

```
echo '<a href="..." onclick="fun()">href_link</a>';
```

...but you have to use JS function

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
function fun()
{
 if(confirm('are you sure')) return TRUE;
 else return FALSE;
}
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```